# find total data in N*N matrix

Tags: python, algorithm

a matrix  consists of N × N blocks .the block number is equal to the sum  of the row number and the column number. each block consists  of data, and data is equal to  difference  of  sum of even and odd digits of the block number . calculate total data of n*n blocks

**i/o format**

```
lets n = 4
so
matrix will be
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
```

so total data  = 2+3+4+5+3+4+5+6+4+5+6+7+5+6+7+8=80

if number of block is 4256 in any case then data in it will be abs(diff(sum(even digits)- sum(odd digits))) which is abs((4+2+6)-(5))= 7

my naive attempt

```
n = int(raw_input())
sum1=0
sum2=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        sum1 = i+j
        diffsum = diff(sum1)
        sum2 = sum2+diffsum
print sum2
```

**again optimized attempt**

```
def diff(sum1):
    sum1 = str(sum1)
    m = sum([int(i) for i in sum1 if int(i) % 2 == 0])
    f = sum([int(i) for i in sum1 if int(i) % 2 != 0])
    return abs(m - f)


n = int(raw_input())
sum1 = 0
k = 1
# t1 = time.time()
p = 2 * n
for i in range(2, n + 2):
    diffsum = diff(i)
    diffsum1 = diff(p)
    sum1 = sum1 + (diffsum * k)
    sum1 = sum1 + (diffsum1 * k)
    p = p - 1
    k = k + 1
sum1 = sum1 - (diff(n + 1) * n)
print sum1
```

**diff is common function in both case. i need more optmization with the following algorithm**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your optimised approach calculates the digit sum only once for each number, so at first sight, there isn't anything to be gained from memoisation.

You can improve the performance of your `diff` function by merging the two loops into one and use a dictionary to look up whether you add or subtract a digit:

```
value = dict(zip("0123456789", (0, -1, 2, -3, 4,-5, 6,-7, 8,-9)))

def diff2(s):
    s = str(s)
    return abs(sum([value[i] for i in s]))
```

This will require a conversion to string. You can get a bit faster (but not much) by calculating the digits by hand:

```
dvalue = [0, -1, 2, -3, 4,-5, 6,-7, 8,-9]

def diff(s):
    t = 0

    while s:
        t += dvalue[s % 10]
        s //= 10

    return abs(t)
```

Finally, you can make use of the fact that you calculate all digit sums from 2 up to 2·n sequentially. Store the digits of the current number in an array, then implement an odometer-like counter. When you increment that counter, keep track of the odd and even digit sums. In 9 of 10 cases, you just have to adjust the last digit by removing its value from the respective sum and by adding the next digit to the other sum.

Here's a program that does this. The function `next` increments the counter and keeps the digit sums of even and odd numbers in `sums[0]` and `sums[1]`. The main program is basically the same as yours, except that the loop has been split into two: One where `k` increases and one where it decreases.

```
even = set(range(0, 10, 2))

def next(num, sums):    
    o = num[0]
    if o in even:
        sums[0] -= o
        sums[1] += o + 1
    else:
        sums[0] += o + 1
        sums[1] -= o

    num[0] += 1

    i = 0
    while num[i] == 10:
        sums[0] -= 10
        num[i] = 0

        i += 1
        o = num[i]
        if o in even:
            sums[0] -= o
            sums[1] += o + 1
        else:
            sums[0] += o + 1
            sums[1] -= o

        num[i] += 1

n = int(raw_input())
total = 0

m = len(str(2 * n + 1))
num = [0] * m
num[0] = 2
sums = [2, 0]

k = 1
for i in range(2, n + 2):
    total += abs(sums[0] - sums[1]) * k
    k += 1
    next(num, sums)    

k = n        
for i in range(n + 2, 2*n + 1):
    k -= 1        
    total += abs(sums[0] - sums[1]) * k
    next(num, sums)

print total
```

I've said above that memoisation isn't useful for this approach. That's not true. You could store the even and odd digit sums of number `i` and make use of it when calculating the numbers `10 * i` to `10 * i + 9`. When you call `diff` in order of increasing `i`, you will have access to the stored sums of `i // 10`.

This isn't significantly faster than the odometer approach, but the implementation is clearer at the cost of additional memory. (Preallocated arrays work better than dictionaries for big `n`. You don't need to reserve space for numbers above `(2*n + 11) / 10`.)

```
def diff(s):
    d = s % 10

    e = ememo[s / 10]
    o = omemo[s / 10]

    if d in even:
        e += d
    else:
        o += d

    if s < smax:
        ememo[s] = e 
        omemo[s] = o    

    return e, o

n = int(raw_input())

total = 0

even = set(range(0, 10, 2))
smax = (2*n + 11) / 10
omemo = smax * [0]
ememo = smax * [0]
omemo[1] = 1

k = 1    
for i in range(2, n + 2):
    e, o = diff(i)
    total += abs(e - o) * k
    k += 1        

k = n        
for i in range(n + 2, 2*n + 1):
    k -= 1   
    e, o = diff(i)     
    total += abs(e - o) * k

print total
```

This could be made even faster if one could find a closed formula for the digit sums, but I think that the absolute function prevents such a solution.

Comment: thanx btw but we can do it better by calculating formula that you were telling

Comment: @bosey: If you can solve it with a closed-form formula, that would be the most efficient of course. I haven't found such a formula, however, and I think that the absolute function in `sum(|odd - even|)` makes finding such a formula difficult.